# Data not being loaded into modal codeigniter

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create a modify item popup. When I click the modify item link it displays the data related to that item in the database my itemID however it does not open up in bootstrap modal. What do I need to add or change in my ajax and controller code for the data to be loaded to my modal rather than a random popup. Thanks for your help.

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('searchModel');
    $this->load->model('itemModal');
}
 public function displayItem(){
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data1['results1'] = $this->itemModal->get_item_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode($data1);      
}
public function updateItem(){
    $id=$this->input->post('rfid');
    $data = array(
        'masterCode' => $this->input->post('masterCode'),
        'itemName' => $this->input->post('itemName'),
        'colorName' => $this->input->post('colorName'),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
        'itemCategory' => $this->input->post('itemCategory'),
        'materialDescription' => $this->input->post('materialDescription'),
        'supplier' => $this->input->post('supplier'),
        'checkoutAllowed' => $this->input->post('checkoutAllowed'),
        'itemDescription' => $this->input->post('itemDescription'),
        'comments' => $this->input->post('comments'),
        'itemCode' => $this->input->post('itemCode'),
        'colorCode' => $this->input->post('colorCode'),
        'locationMade' => $this->input->post('makelocation')
    );
    $this->searchModel->form_update($data, $id);

    //load the header
    $this->load->view('base.php',$data);
    //load the page
    redirect('execute_search');
}
}
```

Model:

```
<?php
class ItemModal extends CI_Model {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function get_item_by_id($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('inventoryID =',$id);

    // Execute the query.
    $query = $this->db->get('inventory');

    // Return the results.
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
?>
```

View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/results.css">
    <title>Results</title>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: auto;
            height: 50px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        th {
            background-color: lightgrey;
            color: black;
        }
        tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center>Item List</center></h1>
    <hr>
     <div class="container">
         <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('itemView/viewItems'); ?>">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th><center><input type="radio" name="id"></center></th>
                        <th>Inventory ID</th>
                        <th>Master Code</th>
                        <th><center>Item Name</center></th>
                        <th>Color Name</th>
                        <th><center>Location</center></th>
                        <th><center>Checkout Allowed</center></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach($results as $rows):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo site_url('Search/displayItem/'.$rows['inventoryID']); ?>" data-target="#modifyItem">Modify Item</a></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('itemView/viewItems/'.$rows['inventoryID']); ?>"><?php echo $rows['inventoryID'] ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['masterCode'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['itemName'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['colorName'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['location'] ?></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" <?php if($rows['checkoutAllowed'] == 'Yes') echo " checked='checked' "; ?>></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
         </form>
        <!-- Modify an Item Modal -->
                <div id="modifyItem" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <form action="<?php echo site_url("Search/updateItem"); ?>" method='POST'>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modify an Item</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">                                     
                                    <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="rfid" readonly/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="itemCode"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="masterCode"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="itemName"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="colorCode"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="colorName"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="location"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="makelocation"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="itemCategory"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="materialDescription"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="supplier"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="checkoutAllowed"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                    <div class="row personal-info">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <textarea name="itemDescription"></textarea>
                                                <textarea name="Comments"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="modifyItem" value="Modify Item">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modify an Item Modal -->
</div><br><br>
</body>
<script>
    function updateItem(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('Search/displayItem');?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function($data1){
                $('[name="rfid"]').val($data1.inventoryID);
                $('[name="masterCode"]').val($data1.masterCode);
                $('[name="masterCode"]').val($data1.itemCode);
                $('[name="itemName"]').val($data1.itemName);
                $('[name="colorName"]').val($data1.colorCode);
                $('[name="colorName"]').val($data1.colorName);
                $('[name="location"]').val($data1.location);
                $('[name="itemCategory"]').val($data1.itemCategory);
                $('[name="materialDescription"]').val($data1.materialDescription);
                $('[name="supplier"]').val($data1.supplier);
                $('[name="checkoutAllowed"]').val($data1.checkoutAllowed);
                $('[name="itemDescription"]').val($data1.itemDescription);
                $('[name="Comments"]').val($data1.comment);
                $('#modifyItem').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I can suggest you that put your modal body in another view file and while retrieving data from database using Ajax generate view and load into your modal body.